# How to draw shapes from a class to an applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, draw, shapes

total programming beginner here, trying to learn some Java over school holidays. Been making simple things and have started looking at GUIs and drawing shapes using Graphics. I've mostly been following tutorials and heaps of answers posted here.

I'm having trouble drawing shapes from my Draw class into my DrawTest applet; as below

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawTest extends Applet 
{
    Draw circle = new Draw();

public void init()  
    {
Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2)); //a left and right panel

JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();  //left panel to draw shapes into
drawPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("Draw shapes from another class");
headerLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
drawPanel.add(headerLabel);

drawPanel.add(circle);
circle.drawing();

JPanel textPanel = new JPanel(); //right panel for text
TextArea output = new TextArea("Circle and oval");
textPanel.add(output);

mainPanel.add(drawPanel);
mainPanel.add(textPanel);
add(mainPanel);
}
}
```

And the Draw class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Draw extends JPanel 
{

    public void drawing()
    {
    repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
super.paintComponent(g);
g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

// a circle (int x, int y, int width, int height,int startAngle, int arcAngle);

g.fillArc(20,20,50,50,0,360);

//this will draw a oval of width 60 & height 40 at (10,30)
g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawOval(10,30,60,40);        
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: Please expand what you mean by 'trouble drawing shapes' - what do you expect to happen and what is happening?

Comment: Sorry for being a bit vague. The left panel should contain a filled circle and an unfilled oval. Currently i get nothing, as alex2410 shows.

Comment: I've changed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that problems because you use swing and awt components together. Use only swing components.

Use `JApplet` instead of `Applet`.

Use `JPanel` instead of `Panel`.

Use `JTextArea` instead of `TextArea`.

Also wrap `JtextArea` with `JSrollPane`, and as mentioned by dehlen you needn't `drawing()` method.

For example change your `init()` method like next :

```
public void init() {
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2)); // a left and right panel

    JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    drawPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("Draw shapes from another class");
    headerLabel.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    drawPanel.add(headerLabel,BorderLayout.EAST);
    circle.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    drawPanel.add(circle);

    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); // right panel for text
    JTextArea output = new JTextArea("Circle and oval");
    textPanel.add(new JScrollPane(output));

    mainPanel.add(drawPanel);
    mainPanel.add(textPanel);
    add(mainPanel);
    setSize(600,200);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the help, that is perfect! Getting my head around layout managers.. arhg.

Comment: You are welcome. Read more about [customPaintings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are mixing awt and swing components. Please type JTextArea and JPanel and JApplet instead of TextArea, Applet and Panel. Also you might want to do something like this:

```
JPanel drawPanel = new Draw();
```

but your solution should work too. Again i think your problem occurs because of mixing awt and swing components.

Also the `circle.drawing();` is unnecessary since the panel calls `paintComponent()` when initializing.